# How to accept CMIS requests with .NET?

Tags: atom-feed, cmis, dms

What are some of the known options for accepting CMIS requests in .NET? I need to accept documents from a CMIS client AtomPub feed and forward them to M-Files DMS which is not CMIS compliant.

Is there a .NET equivalent of the OpenCMIS Server Framework or would this likely be a manual process of consuming the feed?

Answer (score 1):

Use [DotCMIS](https://chemistry.apache.org/dotnet/dotcmis.html) to read from the CMIS repository, then the M-Files .NET API to write to M-Files.